# Any power of logarithm is $O(N)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, asymptotics, computer-science

This is more of a computer science question but it uses calculus and proof techniques so I think it might be more appropriate here. Basically, how do I prove that,

> for any constant $K \geq 1$, that $\log^{K}(N) = O(N)$

Where $O$ denotes the Big O.I am thinking of proving this by induction but not sure what the base case should. In addition to this, I think L'Hopital's rule can be used here with the two functions. Can anyone give me a solid hint on how to start this ? Many thanks !

Comment: Please use LaTeX to make your comment a bit more readable, it's hard on the eyes right now.

Comment: @PravishaJohn The question was $\log^k (n)$, you changed it to $\log(KN)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(\log n)^k}{n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{k (\log n)^{k-1}}{n} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{k(k-1)(\log n)^{k-2}}{n} = \cdots = ?$

By using L'Hospital's rule $k$ times, and assuming $k$ is an integer. If $k$ is not an integer, then use same for $(\log n)^{\lceil k \rceil}$.

Comment: @Alex Using L'Hospital's rule, derivative of numerator is $k (\log n)^k \cdot \frac 1n$, derivative of denominator is $1$. Therefore, the next limit becomes $\dfrac{k (\log n)^{k-1}}{n}$

Comment: ^The derivative should be $k (\log n)^{k-1}\frac1n$. Can't edit comments now.

Answer (score 0):

You can even get a stronger expression, set $\log n =t, n = e^t$, there fore  the limit is 
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^k}{e^t} = 0
$$
Hence $\log n = o(n)$.

Comment: When you wrote log n, did you mean to write ln (n) ? Or does it even matter for this proof ? And maybe I am not really understanding, but the question was log ^ k (N) = O(n). Does the K matter ?